# When trying to click a button that changes sizes in ghost with Playright, the test clicks in it but gives me an error first

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright, ghost-blog

when executing npx playwright test, the test continues by and clicks the button, but it gives me this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLwPu.png)

So, the test goes by, and clicks on the button, but i still get the same error, somebody knows why can this be happening, to clarify the button has a animation that makes the button change sizes.
Code of the test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwgba.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaZjy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8ER7.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `force` click to [escape actionability checks](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/actionability#forcing-actions).

This should bypass actionability checks and not wait for the animation to stop changing.

```
await page.getByRole('button').click({force:true});
```